# Let $E=C([-1,1])$ and $f,g \in E$ such that $f(x) = x^2-1$ and $g(x)= 1-x^2$. Determine if $B(f,2) \cap B(g,2) = \emptyset?$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $E=C([-1,1])$ the set of continuous functions with the sup norm and $f,g \in E$ such that $f(x) = x^2-1$ and $g(x)= 1-x^2$. Determine if $B(f,2) \cap B(g,2) = \emptyset?$

With the sup norm I have that \begin{align*}
d(f,g) &= \|f-g\|_{\infty}\\
&= \sup_{x\in [-1,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|  = \sup_{x\in [-1,1]}|x^2-1-(1-x^2)| \\
&= \sup_{x\in [-1,1]}|2x^2-2|=2
\end{align*}

So this would seem that the intersection is empty, but I'm not entirely sure this concludes it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your result implies that the open balls do not intersect. Try to visualize it, if you take an open ball with the center $g$ then they will intersect obviously, as $g$ lies in the boundary of $B(f,2)$

In fact, $h(x)=x^2$ belongs to both of these open balls